# Struggling with the role of Redux action creators

Tags: redux, react-redux

I'm struggling to get the correct notion of a redux "action". Is it more like a simple message that represents what happened in the user interface and nothing more, or is a fat record holding all the new state?

In the Redux examples I read, actions are always simple CRUD like operations. For the example, when adding a TODO, the view button event handler (or should I say the TODO controller) creates an ADD_TODO action that already contains a full todo object, with a new identifier. The reducer merely inserts the data. Reducers are not "smart".

However, this causes the controller to have a lot of logic to compute the data for an action. It is fine for a simple TODO app, but in more complicated apps a lot of the "business logic " will be contained in these controllers, and not in the reducers (the latter merely performing simple CRUD operations that are always the same really).

So if a controller crashes while creating an action, the action will not be logged at all, and action logging is one of key Redux selling points IMHO.

What are the guidelines for creating actions with complex code to setup the action's data? Should I just put try/catch around these action creators, and use another logging system? Or should I use a thunk for this, splitting the complex action creation into two actions (or 3 if an error occurred, exactly like async API calls are handled)?

Thanks,
Peter

Answer (score 1):

Got a few clarifications for you.

First, there's no specific rules around what actions must contain, other than a `type` field, or whether the bulk of the logic should be in the action creator or the reducer.  It's entirely valid to have an action that's just `{type : "UPDATE_STUFF"}` and have the reducer do all the work, or have the action creator generate the new state and the reducer simply do `return {...state, ...action.payload}`.  I've got a couple discussions on the pros, cons, and tradeoffs of both approachs in the [Redux FAQ on where to put business logic](http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/CodeStructure.html#structure-business-logic), and the "Action Semantics" and "Thick and Thin Reducers" sections of my blog post [Idiomatic Redux: The Tao of Redux, Part 2 - Practice and Philosophy](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/05/idiomatic-redux-tao-of-redux-part-2/).  Quoting myself from that post:

> There's valid tradeoffs with putting more logic in action creators vs putting more logic in reducers. One good point that I saw recently is that if you have more logic in reducers, that means more things that can be re-run if you are time-travel debugging (which would generally be a good thing).
>
> I personally tend to put logic in both places at once. I write action creators that take time to determine if an action should be dispatched, and if so, what the contents should be. However, I also often write corresponding reducers that look at the contents of the action and perform some complex state updates in response.
>
> I generally try to minimize the number of places I do return `{...state, ...action.payload}`. That approach is definitely helpful if I'm doing something like updating multiple possible fields in a form and don't want to write separate `updateName` / `updateAge` / `updateWhatever` handlers for each field.
>
> I would say neither is more "idiomatic" specifically and are perfectly valid choices, but there are some benefits of erring on the side of more logic in reducers.

So, it *is* fine to have "smart" reducers, and I do have some examples of complex reducer logic in my ["Practical Redux" tutorial series](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/series/practical-redux/).

Errors and crashes are going to be an issue no matter whether they occur in action creators or reducers.  In fact, if there's an uncaught error in a reducer, I believe the action still will not be properly recorded in the Redux DevTools.

There's also no specific rules about whether to dispatch a single action, or multiple "sub-actions that form a transaction".  I do have some discussion on that in my post [Idiomatic Redux: Thoughts on Thunks, Sagas, Abstraction, and Reusability](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/01/idiomatic-redux-thoughts-on-thunks-sagas-abstraction-and-reusability/).

And finally, along the lines of your question title, you may also want to read my post [Idiomatic Redux: Why use action creators?](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2016/10/idiomatic-redux-why-use-action-creators/).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write this down so cleanly!

I guess it's because I'm coming from an MVVM background, that I tend to place most logic I my reducers. My state is actually more like a view-model, and less like a model.  

I also didn't dare to normalize my state yet, because IMHO working with IDs and tables everywhere opens up many problems from imperative programming: dangling IDs, undefined object crashes, etc... Having used Haskell for a couple of years, working with a tree feels more natural, but seems discouraged in Redux...

Comment: Yeah, Redux encourages you to store everything as plain serializable data, rather than object references.  I highly recommend using the [Redux-ORM library](https://github.com/tommikaikkonen/redux-orm) for managing normalized relational data in your Redux store.  The "Practical Redux" series I linked talks about using Redux-ORM and demonstrates it in a sample app.  For more info on normalization in Redux, see http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/NormalizingStateShape.html and https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links/blob/master/redux-techniques.md#selectors-and-normalization .

Answer (score 0):

When talking about "actions", I don't think CRUD is the correct word. You should think of reducers as more as transformations. An action is business logic with a "payload" as specific information needed for the transformation.

Reduces are smart because they use the existing state to calculate the next state.

What do you mean by?

> ... a lot of the "business logic " will be contained in these controllers ...

When you talking about "complex code" and "try/catch", if you want to work with APIs, you should use [redux-auto](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-auto).

from the documentation:

[redux-auto](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-auto) fixed this asynchronous problem simply by allowing you to create an "action" function that returns a promise. To accompany your "default" function action logic.

1. No need for other Redux async middleware. e.g. thunk, promise-middleware, saga
2. Easily allows you to pass a promise into redux and have it managed for you
3. Allows you to co-locate external service calls with where they will be transformed
4. Naming the file "init.js" will call it once at app start. This is good for loading data from the server at start

The idea is to have each [action in a specific file](https://github.com/codemeasandwich/redux-auto#action-files). co-locating the server call in the file with reducer functions for "pending", "fulfilled" and "rejected". This makes handling promises very easy.

It also automatically attaches a [helper object (called "async")](https://github.com/codemeasandwich/redux-auto#handling-async-actions-in-your-ui) to the prototype of your state, allowing you to track in your UI, requested transitions.